# CountDownLatch await method issue: doesn't throw on timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, countdownlatch

I am writing a simple program to demonstrate `CountDownLatch`.  Here is my program:

```java
class Players implements Runnable {
    private int delay;
    private String name;
    private CountDownLatch latch;

    Players(int delay, String name, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.delay = delay;
        this.name = name;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Player" + name + "joined");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

```java
public class LudoDemoUsingCountDownLatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(4);
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        service.execute(new Players(11000, "player-1", latch));
        service.execute(new Players(12000, "player-2", latch));
        service.execute(new Players(13000, "player-3", latch));
        service.execute(new Players(14000, "player-4", latch));
        try {
            latch.await(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            System.out.println("All four playesr joined. game started ");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("cant start the game ");
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting that main thread should kick in even before any player is joining and code inside catch block should execute as the waiting time for await method is less than the sleep method of all players threads. But I am not getting that output.  Instead, it is showing that all players joined and the game was started:

output:

```
 1. Player-2joined
 2. Player-3joined
 3. Player-1joined
 4. Player-4joined
 5. All four players joined. game started
```

Comment: where's the code for players? Without that we have no idea on what's going on inside?

Comment: I have edited and added the Players code

Comment: Read the documentation, it returns a boolean if the timeout elapsed. So, use an `if` condition to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the return value of `CountDownLatch.await`.  It doesn't throw `InterruptedException` when it times out; it returns `false`.

So, a corrected version of your `main` method would look like:

```java
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(4);
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
service.execute(new Players(11000, "player-1", latch));
service.execute(new Players(12000, "player-2", latch));
service.execute(new Players(13000, "player-3", latch));
service.execute(new Players(14000, "player-4", latch));
boolean started = false;
try {
    started = latch.await(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (started) {
        System.out.println("All four players joined. game started ");
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Interrupted - won't generally be hit");
}
if (!started) {
    System.out.println("Can't start the game");
}
```

Note that you probably *also* meant to put `System.out.println("Player" + name + "joined");` *after* the `Thread.sleep` call in `Player`.

Comment: Thanks. So `await` returns `true` when resolved before reaching the timeout.